# Add gesture recognizer with Voice Over enabled

Tags: objective-c, ios, gesture, gesture-recognition, voiceover

I'm testing gestures with VoiceOver enabled. I have view which contains instance of UITableView with set property allowsMultipleSelection=YES. I added instance of UITapGestureRecognizer to view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onDoubleTap)];
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
doubleTapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
doubleTapRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
[mainView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

and this work with enabled VoiceOver, when i make 3 taps (1 tap more). But in case  when i select cell (double tap in VoiceOver mode) than cell is selected but i have voice message without information that cell is selected (when i tap once on already selected cell - i have proper information). When I set doubleTapRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO, than selection and voice message is ok in VoiceOver mode, but when i make 3 x tap, my metod onDoubleTap is called but also last focused cell is selected/deselected (like with 2 x tap).
So this solution is not working properly for me.

I found in Iphone User Guide that in VoiceOver mode 3x taps is defined: "Triple-tap: Double-tap an item."- so it is reserved. I tried change taps to numberOfTapsRequired = 3; - but it is not working in VoiceOver mode - i tested that when i put one finger on the sreen and make 3 x taps with second finger that it is work. How this should be done in proper way ? and where  I can find more information how gestures are handled in VoiceOver mode to make proper solution (for example if i add other gesture like long press, how it should be triggered in voice over mode ).

--
Regards 
Adam